# turn excel column into php strings

Tags: php, excel

I have an excel file with a large amount of strings in a column. I want to add these to an array in a php file, so I want each cell in the column to be enclosed in apostrophe's and insert a comma between each. I tried copying the excel column to word and doing a find and replace in word but it uses a different apostrophe type. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at any Excel reader libraries for PHP? or are you working with a CSV file rather than an actual Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

Export the Excel file to .csv, then you can either learn to read .csv files from PHP, e.g., from [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php10p6.html), or do something more pragmatic like open the file in a text editor like BBEdit and select the column you want using block-select mode, discarding the rest of the document.

Comment: thanks, I used notepad++ to do something similar as I'm on windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about the """ but I used a similar method to create SQL queries from cells.

```
="""&A1&""","""&B1&""", ...
```